# Jquery loop 2D form inputs and calculate values per array key

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I am trying to calculate a ticket total based on user input on a form using 2 dimensional names.  I have been searching for 2 days on how to pull all the values at once from each key in the input field names.

```
<input type="text" name="service[]['qty']">
<input type="text" name="service[]['part_number']">
<input type="text" name="service[]['price']">

<input type="text" name="service[]['qty']">
<input type="text" name="service[]['part_number']">
<input type="text" name="service[]['price']">

<input type="text" name="service[]['qty']">
<input type="text" name="service[]['part_number']">
<input type="text" name="service[]['price']">
```

When the user enters the price in the corresponding area, the total for the whole order needs to be calculated and displayed at the bottom of the screen using javascript / jQuery.

Here is the function :

```
function calculate_ticket(){
  var total = 0;
  var data = $("input[name^='service[]']").serializeArray();
  $.each(data, function(i, field){
    $("#ticket_total").append(field.name + ":" + field.value + "<br />"); // for debugging.
  });
  console.debug(data);
  $('#ticket_price').html("$" + total.toFixed(2));
}
```

What I am hoping to do is pull all the data from each key at once and simply multiply the 'price' by the 'qty' then add that to the 'ticket_price'.  The form 'service' input area can have and unlimited number of entries.

Answer (score 0):

I figured a way to do this finally :)

I switched around the name dimension from service[]['qty'] to service['qty'][] and used .serializeArray() on both qty and price.  Here is the function :

```
function calculate_ticket(){
var total = 0;
var price = $("input[name^='service[\\'price\\']']").serializeArray();
var qty = $("input[name^='service[\\'qty\\']']").serializeArray();
$.each(price, function(i, field){
    total += qty[i].value * field.value;
});
$('#ticket_price').html("$" + total.toFixed(2));
}
```